# Subtract Three dimension array from 2D

Tags: java, arrays

I have two data sets, the first one is 3D and the second is 2D.

How can I implement the subtract of the two sets.

:

```
   import java.util.*;
   class test28{

   public static void main ( String[] args ) {
 int [][][] arr1 = {{{6,3,9,0},{8,6,5,3}}};
 int [][] arr2=  {{6,3,9,0},{8,6,5,3}};

     test28 test = new test28();

    System.out.println(test.subtract(arr1,arr2));

     }
  public static int [][] subtract(int[][][] a, int[][] b)  {

   int [][] diff = new int[a.length][a[0].length];

      for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        for ( int j=0; j<a[0].length; j++){
           for ( int k=0; k<a[0][0].length; k++) {

              diff[0][i] = a[i][j][k]- b[i][j];
        }
     }
   }

   return diff;

   }

 }
```

the code below generates an error :

i  changed the diff instantiated,  then i have  indexoutofbound  error

at diff[0][i] = a[i][j][k]- b[i][j];

Comment: Can you provide the error ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by the "difference of the arrays"?

Comment: what's your purpose to subtract the two arrays?

Comment: aditionally add the stacktrace, a sample input, the actual output and the expected output. Otherwise it´s unclear what the intention of this code is.

Answer (score 0):

One reasonable explanation is the following:

```
 int [][] diff = new int[a[0].length][a[0][0].length];

    for ( int j=0; j<a[0].length; j++){
       for ( int k=0; k<a[0][0].length; k++)

          diff[j][k] = a[0][j][k]- b[j][k];
```

Of course the dimensions must match so you have to perform that checking.

I dont see the purpose of this.

Comment: @ gpasch I have  methods in a  program which end with these two type of array, one of them is three dimension, the other two.